# Windows 8 Consumer Preview Wrong Major Version?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windows-8

I am using this code to detect the WindowsVersion on a PC.

```
function GetOS: string;
var
 osVerInfo: TOSVersionInfo;
 majorVer, minorVer: Integer; 
begin
Result := 'Unknown';
osVerInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo);
if GetVersionEx(osVerInfo) then
 begin
  majorVer := osVerInfo.dwMajorVersion;
  minorVer := osVerInfo.dwMinorVersion;
  case osVerInfo.dwPlatformId of
  VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT: {Mirosoft Windows NT/2000 }
    begin
      if majorVer <= 4 then
        Result := 'Win NT'
      else if (majorVer = 5) and (minorVer = 0) then
        Result := 'Win 2k'
      else if (majorVer = 5) and (minorVer = 1) then
        Result := 'Win XP'
      else if (majorVer = 6) and (minorVer = 0) then
        Result := 'Win Vista'
      else if (majorVer = 6) and (minorVer = 1) then
        Result := 'Win 7'
      else if (majorVer = 6) and (minorVer = 2) then
        Result := 'Win 8'
    end;
  VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS:  { Windows 9x/ME }
    begin
      if (majorVer = 4) and (minorVer = 0) then
        Result := 'Win 95'
      else if (majorVer = 4) and (minorVer = 10) then
      begin
        if osVerInfo.szCSDVersion[1] = 'A' then
          Result := 'Win 98SE'
        else
          Result := 'Win 98';
      end
      else if (majorVer = 4) and (minorVer = 90) then
        Result := 'Win ME'
    end;
  end;
end;
end;
```

For some reason it says that Windows8 Consumer Preview Build 8250 (32bit) is Windows XP - Major Version 5. I checked and it's supposed to be Version 6.2 (according to notepad.exe on windows8) Is this a bug or is something wrong? btw. my Windows 8 is up2date.

Any Ideas?

EDIT: ScreenShot
[image: GETOS]

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Check to see what you get back in `osVerInfo` and trace through it to see how you end up with that result.  That'll give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: I looked through the entire osVerInfo and debugged it. It says Major Version 5.

Comment: maybe your app is running under XP compatibility mode ?

Comment: The [GetVersionEx function works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817160/getversionex-under-windows-8) under Windows 8, I just tested a Delphi XE2 application under Windows 8 Developer Preview and the `GetVersionEx` returns 6.2, so has @AntonioBakula says probably your are executing you app in XP compatibility mode.

Comment: That was it. The Delphi7 IDE runs under compatibility mode. I totally forgot about that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then would be fair if @Antonio post that as the answer and you would accept it ;-)

Comment: posted as answer, I wasn't sure that this was a reason so I posted comment :)

Comment: FWIW The Delphi IDE, even for D7, does not need compat mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is XP Compatibility mode, Delphi 7 IDE was running under compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 8.0 the version 6.2 is correct - also the Build-Number.
With Windows 8.1 you get version 6.2 too. But now the Version-Number ist 6.3 Build 9600. You can see it in the system-info.
GetVersionEx allows only 0,1,2 for Win32MinorVersion.
If you need this info, you can read it from registry-key 'Version' in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\WindowsSearch.
Best regards,
asks