# Retrieving OS Name of MS Windows Platform

Tags: c++, windows, wmi, wmi-query

I need to get information on OS Name of MS Windows Platform. I've googled it and found **GetVersionEx** would do it. But I just need OS Name, is there any simplest way of achieving it? not using **system()** Guide me thanks...

I am using this code using **WMI**:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
    // Note: If you are using Windows 2000, you need to specify -
    // the default authentication credentials for a user by using
    // a SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_LIST structure in the pAuthList ----
    // parameter of CoInitializeSecurity ------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
         _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
         NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
         NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
         0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
         NULL,                    // Security flags.
         0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
         0,                       // Context object 
         &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
         );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       NULL,                        // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                        // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << " OS Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    pclsObj->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```

At the time of debugging, I will get break or continue message box!? with following message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00412058 in osname.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef6.

And I am getting the output correctly. But it terminates.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: WMI should generally be used when there is no other solution. It's a last resort. Look at all the hoops you have to jump through to get the thing going.

Comment: Well thanks :) plz compile the given code under **GetVersionEx**, if you get correct output, then let me know because I am not able to compile it properly, thanks again..

Comment: it compiled, but a garbage output is shown on Console window?

Comment: Got it to work by using the code presented in the answer here :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817160/getversionex-under-windows-8

Comment: So you found a non-WMI solution? Good - WMI can be a huge pain. If you're going to abandon WMI for your answer, you can actually post the answer w/link as an Answer below, and mark it as the answer. Would be good for others to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution. If anyone gets .dll missing error, recompile it in Release mode (I am VC++ 2010 FYI).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

#define BUFSIZE 256

typedef void (WINAPI *PGNSI)(LPSYSTEM_INFO);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGPI)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, PDWORD);

BOOL GetOSDisplayString( LPTSTR pszOS)
{
   OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
   SYSTEM_INFO si;
   PGNSI pGNSI;
   PGPI pGPI;
   BOOL bOsVersionInfoEx;
   DWORD dwType;

   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));
   ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));

   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
   bOsVersionInfoEx = GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*) &osvi);

   if( ! bOsVersionInfoEx ) return 1;

   // Call GetNativeSystemInfo if supported or GetSystemInfo otherwise.

   pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(
      GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), 
      "GetNativeSystemInfo");
   if(NULL != pGNSI)
      pGNSI(&si);
   else GetSystemInfo(&si);

   if ( VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT==osvi.dwPlatformId && 
        osvi.dwMajorVersion > 4 )
   {
      StringCchCopy(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Microsoft "));

      // Test for the specific product.

      if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 6 )
      {
         if( osvi.dwMinorVersion == 0 )
         {
            if( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows Vista "));
            else StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows Server 2008 " ));
         }

         if ( osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1 || osvi.dwMinorVersion == 2 )
         {
            if ( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1)
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows 7 "));
            else
            if ( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 2)
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows 8 "));
            else 
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows Server 2008 R2 " ));
         }

         pGPI = (PGPI) GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), 
            "GetProductInfo");

         pGPI( osvi.dwMajorVersion, osvi.dwMinorVersion, 0, 0, &dwType);

         switch( dwType )
         {
            case PRODUCT_ULTIMATE:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Ultimate Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Professional" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Home Premium Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Home Basic Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Enterprise Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_BUSINESS:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Business Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_STARTER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Starter Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_CLUSTER_SERVER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Cluster Server Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Datacenter Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Datacenter Edition (core installation)" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Enterprise Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Enterprise Edition (core installation)" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_IA64:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Enterprise Edition for Itanium-based Systems" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Small Business Server" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Small Business Server Premium Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Standard Edition" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Standard Edition (core installation)" ));
               break;
            case PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER:
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Web Server Edition" ));
               break;
         }
      }

      if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 2 )
      {
         if( GetSystemMetrics(SM_SERVERR2) )
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Windows Server 2003 R2, "));
         else if ( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_STORAGE_SERVER )
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Windows Storage Server 2003"));
         else if ( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_WH_SERVER )
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Windows Home Server"));
         else if( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION &&
                  si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64)
         {
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Windows XP Professional x64 Edition"));
         }
         else StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows Server 2003, "));

         // Test for the server type.
         if ( osvi.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
         {
            if ( si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 )
            {
                if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Datacenter Edition for Itanium-based Systems" ));
                else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Enterprise Edition for Itanium-based Systems" ));
            }

            else if ( si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 )
            {
                if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Datacenter x64 Edition" ));
                else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Enterprise x64 Edition" ));
                else StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Standard x64 Edition" ));
            }

            else
            {
                if ( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_COMPUTE_SERVER )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Compute Cluster Edition" ));
                else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Datacenter Edition" ));
                else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Enterprise Edition" ));
                else if ( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_BLADE )
                   StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Web Edition" ));
                else StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Standard Edition" ));
            }
         }
      }

      if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1 )
      {
         StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows XP "));
         if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_PERSONAL )
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Home Edition" ));
         else StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Professional" ));
      }

      if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 0 )
      {
         StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Windows 2000 "));

         if ( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
         {
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Professional" ));
         }
         else 
         {
            if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Datacenter Server" ));
            else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
               StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Advanced Server" ));
            else StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( "Server" ));
         }
      }

       // Include service pack (if any) and build number.

      if( _tcslen(osvi.szCSDVersion) > 0 )
      {
          StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT(" ") );
          StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, osvi.szCSDVersion);
      }

      TCHAR buf[80];

      StringCchPrintf( buf, 80, TEXT(" (build %d)"), osvi.dwBuildNumber);
      StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, buf);

      if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion >= 6 )
      {
         if ( si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 )
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT( ", 64-bit" ));
         else if (si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL )
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, TEXT(", 32-bit"));
      }

      return TRUE; 
   }

   else
   {  
      printf( "This sample does not support this version of Windows.\n");
      return FALSE;
   }
}

int __cdecl _tmain()
{
    TCHAR szOS[BUFSIZE];

    if( GetOSDisplayString( szOS ) )
    {
        _tprintf( TEXT("\n%s\n"), szOS );
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works as long as you add the [compatibility manifest](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx) elements with the GUIDS for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. That said, why is this level of detail even needed?